# Why Am I Getting A Parse Error?

Tags: php

I have an HTML page with a simple form on it that submits data to login.php. Inside of login.php I have this code. When I try to execute this script I get this error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/login.php on line 13

```
<?php

$username = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($username&&$password) {

    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "admin", "1455m") or die("Couldn't Connect");
    mysql_select_db("lr") or die("Couldn't find database!");

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'")

    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if ($numrows!=0) {

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

            $dbusername = $row['username'];
            $dbpassword = $row['password'];
        }

        if ($username==$dbusername&&$password==$dbpassword) {

            echo 'You are In!';

        } else {

            echo 'Incorrect Password!';
        }

    } else {
        die("That user doesn't exist.");
    }

} else {
    die("Please enter a username & password.");
}

?>
```

Comment: Grammar police: You spelled "You're" wrong.

Comment: @rhooligan that is why we have the edit button

Comment: @lbu well it is in OP's code so figured he might want to fix it.

Comment: @Ken Not only is changing spelling within OP's code not helping OP find and change it, but adding an apostrophe to the statement `echo 'Your In!';` (changed to `echo 'You're In!';`) actually breaks functionality there.

Comment: @rhooligan: If you want to criticize grammar, go to a grammar site. Your comment is inappropriate and non-constructive here. Please don't behave like that - English isn't always everyone's first language, and grammar is less important than being able to express your question in a way people can understand. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, no need to grammar police it up. The ' in the echo string now needs to be escaped however. `echo 'You\'re in';` etc

Comment: @JYelton: Thanks. Missed the breakage in the highlighting. I only fixed the spelling to quiet the "grammar police" comments. I really couldn't care (as you can see by my prior comment).

Comment: I'd appreciate spelling and grammar oversights within my code to be pointed out, but I agree it could be done with a little gentler prod in that direction. :)

Comment: Would you like to accept the answer?

Answer (score 9):

You're missing a semicolon:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'") 
                                                                      ^
                                                                      Here
```

Comment: Seriously... LMAO. WOW. Thank You haha.

Comment: @user1435650: If this answers your question, you should accept it as the correct answer. Please take a few minutes to read this [meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Accepting answers lets others know that your problem has been solved, shows appreciation to the person that helped you solve it, and as a bonus earns you some reputation as well. :)

Comment: I dont think you're getting your tick @nickb :( +1 anyway ;)

Answer (score 3):

That error is telling you that something on line 13 was unexpected; in this case a variable. So usually it's a good idea to check the code that comes before it and check that it's syntactically correct.

In this case you're missing a semi-colon on the line proceeding line 13, so line 11 due to your formatting - just where you use mysql_query()! Try this...

```
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "admin", "1455m") or die("Coudn't Connect");
mysql_select_db("lr") or die("Coudn't find database!");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'"); // here!

$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

Answer (score -2):

You are forgetting to add the connection in the query:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
```

should be:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'", $connect);
```

Comment: mysql_query() doesn't require the second argument (the connection) if there is only one connection to the database at that time. [PHP mysql_query() docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)